# Unable to run Grpc solution in .Net core

Tags: c#, ssl, grpc, .net-5

Hi I am working in Grpc application using .Net 5. I have created sample Greeter service and console application as client application. I followed article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio. When I run the solution I get below error

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.",
```

I went to trouble shoot guide in Microsoft page and tried all the ways but still no luck.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-a-grpc-service-with-an-untrustedinvalid-certificate

Below is my client application code.

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The port number(5001) must match the port of the gRPC server.
            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
            var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
            var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(
                              new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Below is LunchSettings.json in my GrpcGreeter

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "GrpcGreeter": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000;https://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me to identify this issue and fix the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The last time I saw this error a few weeks ago the certificate wasn't install properly on the remote machine.

Comment: What certificate is being used here? If it is a self-issued Dev cert, it'll need to be manually installed on the client machine, as there won't be a valid trust chain

Comment: Thanks all. Currently I am working in localhost. for localhost what certificate should I use and from where I will get those?